# Prove that if $x\in\{a,b\}^*$ and $abx=xab$, then $x = (ab)^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: computational-complexity, formal-languages

This is an exercise in text "Computability, Complexity, and Languages" by Davis et al.:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjW0y.png)

I can prove it easily by mathematical induction, but this exercise appears after a section titled "Proof by Contradiction", so it is supposed to be proved by deriving a contradiction.

Following is my attempt. From condition $abx=xab$ I can say $x$ begins with and end in $ab$, so I write $x$ as $abuab$ for some string $u$. After plugging it into $abx=xab$ and cancelling $ab$, I got $abu=uab$, which seems to imply nothing contradictory. If I proceed this way by writing $u$ as $abvab$, the same equation results again and again except the variable name. Then I tried to deny the conclusion, but I have difficulty in expressing $x$ in a way easy to proceed when $x\neq(ab)^n$. Can you please give me some hint (you don't have to follow my unsuccessful attempt)? Thank you.

Comment: A proof by contradiction could start with assuming $ x \not=(ab)^n$ for all $n$ and by picking some $x$ with minimal length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really already have what I suspect is the intended argument; you just have to look at it properly. Assume that there is a counterexample; then there is a shortest counterexample. Your argument now shows how to get a shorter counterexample and hence a contradiction.

As far as I’m concerned this is really just another way of thinking about induction, but it is technically a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Ah, yes, shortest! The technique of "shortest" is also used in P261 of the textbook, but I forgot it. Thank you so much for reminding me of this cool tool for constructing a contradiction.

Comment: @zzzhhh: You’re very welcome.